# Multiple UIView animations hitting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm animating two `uiviews` using `CGAffineTransform`

For 1st view:

```
swingView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(swingView.transform, M_PI/2);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     swingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

For second view

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

    CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-120, 0);
     myview.transform = transform1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here two `views` are **hitting** when `animation` starts, what i have to do to not allow hitting between these `uiviews`.

Comment: are you calling this in a same method??

Comment: Nope.. one in viewdidload, another in other method..

Comment: what you want is, animate the first view and when it finished, start the second ? ( sorry for my bad understood else )